# Recursive Function to check array length

Tags: javascript, jquery, recursion

I have an array named runningTimers which has a list of timers which are running in the background and haven't completed. Each timer runs for a period of 500ms. If the user presses submit button I want them to wait for those timers to finish before the form is submitted.

Below is my recursive function which checks for length of the array. When the array is empty it should return.

```
function checkTimers() {
    if (runningTimers.length < 1) {
        return true;
    } else {
        checkTimers();
    }
}
```

Below is the jQuery code on submit button.

```
$(document).on("click","#checkoutbtn",function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var checkVariable = checkTimers();
    if (checkVariable == true) {
       $(this).html("<i class='fa fa-spinner fa-spin'></i>");
       $(this).prop('disabled',true);

       $("#cartform").submit();
    }

});
```

Following is how runningTimers is set

```
var runningTimers = [];
function updateQuantity(dataString,oid, context) {
    if (timername[oid]) {
        clearTimeout(timername[oid]);
    }
    if (runningTimers.indexOf(oid) == -1) {
        runningTimers.push(oid);
    } 
    timername[oid] = setTimeout(function() {
        const index = runningTimers.indexOf(oid);
        if (index > -1) {
            runningTimers.splice(index,1);
            console.log("removed");
        }
        //Ajax code here
        
    },500);
}
```

I get the following error:

```
Uncaught RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded
    at checkTimers (cart:692)
```

Comment: if nothing will ever make it not true, why does it need to repeat at all? If you aren't using the return value, why does it need to return at all?

Comment: DON'T USE TIMERS if you can possibly avoid it.

Comment: I am using timers because I want to wait before I update quantity in the cart in database instead of immediately.

Comment: This is probably a better use case for a callback or a promise-- the way you are using recursion will have it rapidly recursing unbounded and it quickly reaches the maximum level of recursion depth where JS throws an error.

Comment: That's not possible using a recursive function that immediately calls itself without giving the event loop a chance to process async actions.

Comment: Please review [ask], especially the section titled "Write a title that summarizes the specific problem". "Recursive Function - JavaScript" describes several thousand questions on Stack Overflow, not this specific problem.

Comment: Your `checkTimers()` is causing an infinite loop.  What is the _rest_ of the code doing?  It sounds like you want a `Promise` or something here instead.

Comment: @KevinB updated the code to reflect the requirement of return value.

Comment: i thinl you want to use a `setInterval`

Comment: setInterval inside the recursive function? @DanielA.White

Comment: @SaadBashir no outside - use it to do your periodic checking

Comment: What is setting/changing `runningTimers`?  You probably want `new Promise` or `Promise.all()` or something like that.

Comment: @Daniel tried using setInterval(function(){ checkTimers(); }, 200); in the jQuery part but returns the same error.

Comment: @RocketHazmat updated the question by adding runningTimers part of code

Comment: Does this answer your question? [jQuery: Submit a form only if no AJAX is currently running on the page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13166176/jquery-submit-a-form-only-if-no-ajax-is-currently-running-on-the-page)

Answer (score 1):

When you call `checkTimers()`, it keeps calling it over and over and basically makes an infinite loop.  You never give the browser a chance to do anything else, so it just keeps running `checkTimers()` until it dies.

I would suggest refactoring this away from `setTimeout()` and use `Promise` instead.  This lets you run the code in the background and it will run a callback once it's done.  (Or since you're using jQuery, we can use its `Deferred` objects.)

```
let ajaxCalls = [];

function updateQuantity(dataString, oid, context) {
    ajaxCalls.push($.ajax(...));
}
```

The `$.ajax()` method returns a [`jqXHR`](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/#jqXHR) object, which we can use as a `Deferred`.

Then you can use `$.when()` to "wait" for all them to finish before running a callback.

```
$(document).on("click","#checkoutbtn",function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    $.when.apply($, ajaxCalls).then(() => {
        $(this).html("<i class='fa fa-spinner fa-spin'></i>");
        $(this).prop('disabled',true);
        $("#cartform").submit();
    });
});
```